# Update a row across several data.tables (or data.frames) in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data.table, plyr

I'm trying to build an (efficient) agent-based model in R. Each agent has information captured in a data.table in a list.  Is there a more efficient way to do this than what I have?  Here's some simplified code:

```
require(data.table)

# Setup simulation
numAgents <- 5
numIterations <- 10

# Create collection of agents which have a property someValue that we want to track through the simulation
agents <- vector("list", numAgents)

for(i in 1:numAgents) {
  agents[[i]] <- data.table(someValue1 = rep(as.integer(NA), numIterations), someValue2 = rep(as.integer(NA), numIterations))
}

# Iterate through simulation
for(i in 1:numIterations) {
  # Generate values for someValue1, someValue2 for the agents
  #   Note: This is just to give an idea of what will be involved
  #   Note2: The values depend upon history and other agents
  agentValues1 <- lapply(agents, function(x) {
                                   sum(x[, median(someValue1, na.rm = TRUE)], round(runif(1)), na.rm = TRUE)
                                 })
  agentValues2 <- ifelse(runif(numAgents) < as.integer(agentValues1)/max(as.integer(agentValues1)), 1, 0)

  # Update the agents history (I'm trying to optimize this)
  for(k in 1:numAgents) {
    set(agents[[k]], i, j = "someValue1", as.integer(agentValues1[k]))
    set(agents[[k]], i, j = "someValue2", as.integer(agentValues2[k]))
  }
}
```

A recommendation for not using lists of data.tables would also be welcome, but might be expanding the scope of the question a bit much.

As a note, the value generation process involves (1) multiple properties of the agent (e.g., someValue1 and someValue2) (2) the history of these properties, and (3) the behaviors of other agents.  It's not reflected in the sample code (yet), since I haven't thought of a simple way to reflect it... will update when I can.

---

[EDIT] Code revised to include multiple agent properties and sample value generation that is both history and other agent dependent.  The value generation process in the sample code isn't inherently meaningful, but is meant to be illustrative of the type of dependencies in the real code.

Comment: It's early and maybe I'm half sleeping, but I don't see any data.tables in your code.

Comment: @Roland Sorry, I left it off accidentally, but put it in now.  It doesn't serve a large purpose in the sample code, but in the real code it's used to aggregate the agent's history as part of the value generation process.  I'll try to update the code to be more reflective of this if/when I can think of simple code to insert.

Comment: As a "just after I posted" thought, I'm starting to think my solution is to simply use 1 large data.table, i.e., `agents <- data.table(expand.grid(1:numAgents, 1:numIterations), someValue = as.integer(NA))` `rename(agents, c("Var1" = "agent", "Var2" = "iteration"))`. Then I would just need to update multiple rows in a data.table (with different values) rather than individuals rows in multiple data.tables in a list...  Still not sure though.

Comment: Yes, use one data.table and use `runif` in conjunction with `by` to create your random values.

Comment: Yes data.table much prefers one big data.table to a list of data.table. +1 to @Roland's comment. Don't forget `list` columns too (where each cell is itself a vector), not sure if that's useful here or not.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it preferable to use a matrix to store the agent values:

```
numAgents <- 5
numIterations <- 10

agents <- matrix(NA, nrow=numAgents, ncol=numIterations)

for(i in 1:numIterations) {
  agentValues <- as.integer(ceiling(runif(numAgents)*10))
  agents[,i] <- agentValues
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- in my simplification of the code, I left off that the value generation process depends on multiple properties of the agent (e.g., someValue1, someValue2, etc.), other agents, as well as the history of these values.  I think the latter two can be accommodated through (or in parallel with) the matrix formulation, but not the first one.